# how to switch back to ATI card after using switcheroo?

Tags: ati, acer, radeon, hybrid-graphics, vgaswitcheroo

I have been using switcheroo to turn off my ATI Radeon HD5650 using the switch:

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

This has worked perfectly. I've added it to `/etc/rc.local`.

The Intel graphics card is fine for most of my day to day work and I get huge battery life compared to the Radeon card.

Lately though, I've been trying to run some graphically intensive apps which will not run under the intel chipset.

If I try to run:

```
echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

my laptop (Acer TimelineX 3820tg) just crashes - I have to REiSUB to recover.

My questions are:

1. How am I supposed to turn the ATI card back on when needed?
2. Assuming I'm doing the right thing by using `echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` - should I file a bug report? and if so where?

Any feedback would be *most* appreciated.

I'm currently running Ubuntu 11.04 on (as mentioned) an Acer TimelinX 3820tg using the gnome classic desktop.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with `echo DDIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`?

It works fine on mi laptop with AMD5650/Intel Switchable graphics.